# How to update a polymorphic image in a rake task?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Toilet and Photo model and Photo has a polymorphic association. 
I have a rake task that is gathering information from a csv file. I want to update the image but since it's not part of the toilets table I'm having trouble figuring that out. I'm using paperclip to handle my images.

my task looks like this

```
 namespace :import do
  desc "Importing toilets from csv"
  task toilets: :environment do
   filename = File.join Rails.root, "toilets.csv"
   counter = 0
   CSV.foreach(filename,  headers: true) do |row|
     toilet = Toilet.create(
     name:        row['name'], 
     latitude:     row['latitude'], 
     longitude:  row['longitude'],
     address:   row['address'],
     image:      row['image']
     )
   puts "#{toilet} - #{toilet.errors.full_messages.join(",")}" if toilet.errors.any?
   counter += 1 if toilet.persisted?
  end
  puts "Imported #{counter} toilets"
 end
end
```

Toilet Model

```
has_many :photos, :as => :imageable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

Photo Model

```
 belongs_to :toilet
 belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true

 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to update the image with the code below. This works but I feel that there might be a cleaner solution.

```
 toilet = Toilet.create(
  name:        row['name'], 
  latitude:     row['latitude'], 
  longitude:  row['longitude'],
  address:   row['address']
 )


 photo = Photo.create(
  image: row["image"],
  imageable_type: "Toilet",
  imageable_id: toilet.id
 )
```